# mean function throws error "Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1"

Tags: matlab, mean

I am trying to find the arithmetic mean of a vector in MATLAB. However, when I pass my array into the mean function, it throws the error "Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1." I cannot figure out what is wrong and it's driving me wild because it seems simple. Code excerpt below:

```
streamflows = [24500 16400 15800 12800 12200 12000 11200 11100 9660 9290 8800 8650 8560 8540 8490 8280 8150 8130 8070 7700 7700 7530 7420 7410 7330 7170 7050 6900 6900 6870 6870 6840 6770 6760 6700 6450 6360 6220 6200 6160 6090 6020 5960 5950 5890 5670 5460 5450 5370 5280 5120 5120 5010 4920 4850 4800 4780 4770 4730 4670 4650 4650 4520 4480 4470 4390 4380 4360 4350 4280 4260 4190 4190 4180 4120 4100 4060 4060 4020 4020 3980 3930 3920 3910 3880 3780 3680 3600 3480 3450 3340 3280 3240 3240 3110 2990 2960 2760 2690 2650 2490 2380 2260 2250 2190 2060 1610 1580];

variance = var(streamflows);
skew = skewness(streamflows);
M = mean(streamflows);
```

I tried putting the array directly into the mean() command, and the same error occurred. I also tried changing the order of the three statistic commands, which did not resolve the issue either.

Comment: You probably created a variable `mean` that hides the function. You should not use common function names as variable names. `clear mean` should fix that.